# Change Android L keyboard enter key color

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-theme

The new Android L keyboard uses system theme's colorAccent as the background color of enter key, which doesn't match app's custom theme. Is there a way to change that?

I would assume that there is a theme/style for keyboard, but I couldn't find it in themes_material.xml, the only style I found is android:keyboardViewStyle, but it gives "Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardViewStyle'."

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyboard is a separate app.  There is no api for setting the color of a given key, and many keyboards support no styling at all.  SO there isn't a general way to do this.